# Get text between \ and \PARTS from file name string vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, directory, strip

I need to obtain a value of everything between \ & \PARTS

Example:

```
`XamoutOFdirectorys\THIS IS WHAT I WANT\PARTS`

resulting in the text,  THIS IS WHAT I WANT

in dir1\dir2\THIS IS WHAT I WANT\PARTS

I want the text THIS IS WHAT I WANT and not dir2\THIS IS WHAT I WANT
```

How can I achive that?

The reason is that I need to know what the files name is that is found before the PARTS directory, regardless of howmany directorys are found before and after...

the closest i can achive is ...

```
        Dim text As String = "fat\dir1\dir2\PARTS\bat"
    Dim str As String = text.Split("\"c, "\PARTS"c)(1)
    MsgBox(str)
```

Comment: For files and directories, see the [**Path class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim str As String = "fat\dir1\dir2\PARTS\bat"
    Dim dir As Match = Regex.Match(str, "\\([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\\PARTS")
    MsgBox(dir.Groups(1).ToString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx)

It should return an array with each text between `"\"`. Then you can search for the text `"PARTS"` and take the previous index.

```
Split -> [dir1, dir2, your text, PARTS]

index of PARTS = 3

index of your text = 2
```

I don't really know `vb.net` but that's how I would do it with any other language.

Comment: The question asks how to do it in `.net`. Also, your link is to documentation in Spanish. Stack Overflow is an English speaking website, please reference English documentation in future :)

Comment: `String.Split()` would be better since it's a native .NET method. `Split()` is outdated and were used in older versions of VB.

Comment: @Smittey : Not spanish anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If your path variable type is String. You can find "\PARTS" in path, get the start index A in path. Then find another index B of last "\" before A. Using substring function to get what you want between range [B, A] in path variable:

```
Dim str As String = "fat\dir1\XamoutOFdirectorys\_THIS IS WHAT I WANT\PARTS\bat"
Dim beginIdx, endIdx As Integer
endIdx = str.LastIndexOf("\PARTS") - 1
beginIdx = str.LastIndexOf("\", endIdx - 1) + 1
Dim result = str.Substring(beginIdx, endIdx - beginIdx + 1)
```

By the way, there are more elegant methods such as regular expression. But I really advice you should read MSDN about String, dirt your hand, get the solution by yourself. There are also many solution about "split path" in Stack Overflow that you can change them after you understand the solution. Best regards.

### regular expression like this:

```
Dim str As String = "fat\dir1\XamoutOFdirectorys\_THIS IS REALLY WHAT YOU WANT.&%+\PARTS"
Dim dir As Match = Regex.Match(str, "\\([^\\]+)\\PARTS")
MsgBox(dir.Groups(1).ToString)
```

Which can work in real world and support all possible path versions(tested in windows system).

And the state machine illustration of my regular expression

```
\\([^\\]+)\\PARTS
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/rYms5zrhWCby_FdP

Comment: @p3tch the answer do not consider all possible condition in real world, what if the folder's name has special character like "_", "-", blank space and other language character?